# How to add apostrophe to columns of string type?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple dataframe which has some string cloumns:

```
Name      age address
micheal   21  Washington
Jhon      10 San Franciso
```

I wish to add apostrophe to each string type column, I need to check
the column type and change it accordingly so the outcome would be:

```
Name       age  address
'micheal'  21   'Washington'
'Jhon'     20   'San Francisco'
```

I do  not how much columns I will have, so I need to dynamically query the column type.

Answer (score 1):

There are two requirements then:

> I wish to add apostrophe to each string type column
>
> I do not how much columns I will have

```
// load the dataset from a CSV file
val names = spark.
  read.
  option("header", true).
  option("inferSchema", true).
  csv("names.txt")
scala> names.show
+-------+---+------------+
|   Name|age|     address|
+-------+---+------------+
|micheal| 21|  Washington|
|   Jhon| 10|San Franciso|
+-------+---+------------+
```

For this particular case the schema is as follows:

```
scala> names.printSchema
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
```

We've got two fields of string type, but given the requirement that we don't know how many columns we will have that does not really matter.

That's where Spark SQL's DataFrame API for Scala may actually help where the rows are of type `Dataset[Row]`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
scala> names.collect.head.isInstanceOf[Row]
res0: Boolean = true
```

From [org.apache.spark.sql.Row's scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row):

> Represents one row of output from a relational operator. Allows both generic access by ordinal, which will incur boxing overhead for primitives, as well as native primitive access.

With all that said, the solution could be as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def quoteStringColumns(df: DataFrame) = {

  import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructType}
  def stringFieldNames(schema: StructType) = {
    schema.filter(_.dataType == StringType).map(_.name)
  }
  val columns = stringFieldNames(names.schema)

  val quoteUDF = udf { s: String => s"'$s'" }
  columns.foldLeft(df) { case (resultDF, c) => resultDF.withColumn(c, quoteUDF(col(c))) }
}

val r = quoteStringColumns(names)
scala> r.show
+---------+---+--------------+
|     Name|age|       address|
+---------+---+--------------+
|'micheal'| 21|  'Washington'|
|   'Jhon'| 10|'San Franciso'|
+---------+---+--------------+
```

Comment: Hi:) I already accepted the answer, but beacuse I'm new user my acceptence is calculated but does not appear publicly. Thank again!

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple solution is to `map` over `dtypes` and `select`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, concat, lit}

val exprs = df.dtypes.map {
 // if column is a string concat with quotes and alias
  case (c, "StringType") => concat(lit("'"), col(c), lit("'")).alias(c)
  // otherwise keep as is.
  case (c, _) => col(c)
}

df.select(exprs: _*).show
```

```
+---------+---+---------------+
|     Name|age|        address|
+---------+---+---------------+
|'michael'| 21|   'Washington'|
|   'Jhon'| 20|'San Francisco'|
+---------+---+---------------+
```